# Disable all Hover opening

Tags: html, css

How do I disable all of them from opening when I hover with the mouse?

I just want the icon I'm on to open.

Can someone tell me the best approach for this ?

Thank you.

[before hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXt7Y.png)

[after hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtUwd.png)

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/mraliaras/pen/QWKGXLK)

[repl.it view](http://social-media.aliaras2.repl.co)

[repl.it source files](https://repl.it/@AliAras2/social-media#index.html)

> When I come on it with the mouse, I just want that column to slide.
> There are all the codes in the codepen.io, but the icons are not
> visible.

```css
.top-social-bg {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 60%);
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="top-social-bg" >
    <ul id="top-social">
        <li><a href="#" class="si-call"><span class="ts-icon"><i class="icon-call" style="color:white"></i></span><span class="ts-text">telephone</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="si-email3"><span class="ts-icon"><i class="icon-envelope-alt" style="color:white"></i></span><span class="ts-text">email</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="si-facebook" target="_blank"><span class="ts-icon"><i class="icon-facebook" style="color:white"></i></span><span class="ts-text">facebook</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="si-instagram" target="_blank"><span class="ts-icon"><i class="icon-instagram" style="color:white"></i></span><span class="ts-text">instagram</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make the question clearer?

Comment: When I come on it with the mouse, I just want that column to slide. There are all the codes in the codepen.io, but the icons are not visible.

Comment: Ah, okay thanks for the clarification could you post that into the question, so the future answers can be more helpful?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you the correct direction, without seeing how your css is defined for icons I'm assuming you have a `.top-social-bg:hover` (...followed by maybe `li` `a` or `i` or `i:before`?)...`

You place the hover where you want hover detected, and then change the css for the child element.  You need to specify a style that is specific to the icon.

For example

```
.top-social-bg li:hover i { display:block;}
```

or perhaps it's

```
.top-social-bg li:hover i:before { display:block;}
```

And then define a class for how it should appear when not hovered.

```
.top-social-bg li i { display:none;}
```

or perhaps it's

```
.top-social-bg li i:before { display:none;}
```

Comment: Hi Benson, Unfortunately I couldn't. I've added the look here. http://social-media.aliaras2.repl.co/  https://repl.it/@AliAras2/social-media#index.html

Comment: You'll have to use `position: absolute` to break out of the box model on the `a`tag elements.  That element is growing on hover (or rather an element in the `a` tag).  I would place the hover on the a tag directly.  The element that grows on hover won't cause its parent element to grow if styled with `position:absolute`